# Two Layout files are showing unknown symbols

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I had a problems with build files then i delete it and try to sync 
then i find two of my activity has something like this

[layout.xml](https://gist.github.com/alihabbash/f9328b5bd2325f496545480c8c3a076d)

I tried to open it with Gedit and got the same result.
Can anyone help me to restore this files?

Comment: How is your encoding configuration in your project?

Comment: it's `UTF-8 system defalut`